# Open a geojson of 4 gb in R

Tags: r

I downloaded the file with Italy data from OpenAdress (https://batch.openaddresses.io/job/158537) and I got a 3.57 gb Geojson and I wanted to try to read it with R, but the packages I tried fail because it gives me that the Ram is exhausted (my PC has 8 gb). I have tried with sf, geojsonsf, jsonlite and rjson. Advice on how to do it?

Comment: If your institution has supercomputer or high performance computing cluster, you can request much more RAM and run R on it. But if not, you can try AWS (amazon web services). If you are a student, you should have 200 dollars for free. But it may be complicated to do, if you are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in my PC, but I have 16 gb of RAM, maybe in your PC it won't work:

```
library(jsonlite)
#the path of the Geojson file
file_name <- "D:/it_countrywide-addresses-country.geojson/it_countrywide-addresses-country.geojson"
job<-jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(readLines(file_name)),verbose=F,pagesize =100000,skipNul=T )
```

It took a while to import the data, with the memory usage always near to 95-97%
If you need just part of the file you can play with the `n` argument of `readLines`

**EDIT**

I find [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/02/importing-large-ndjson-files-into-r/) that can be useful. Try to take a look

Comment: does `sf <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(file_name)` work on your system?